# How do I check if the preceding letter of the word that I am looking for in a string exist? Recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am currently creating a java program that counts the number of occurrences of a specific word in a string using recursion, however, if the preceding letter is an 'a', the count won't be incremented. I cannot find a way to check the preceding letter before the first letter of the word I am looking for. I tried using indexOf then subtracting one to check the preceding letter, but it won't work.

Here's my working function at the moment:

```
//The value of text is abrichbbarichacrich
//While the value of find is rich
//Expected output should be 2
static int Count(String text, String find) {
    if (text.length() == 0 || text.length() < find.length()) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (text.contains(find)) {
        return 1 + Count(text.replaceFirst(find, ""), find);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's my second version, but it gives me a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException and the output should be 2, but instead it gives me an output of 3.

```
if (text.length() == 0 || text.length() < find.length()) {
    return 0;
}
if (text.contains(find)) {
    int index = text.indexOf(find) - 1;
    if (text.charAt(index) == 'a')
        return Count(text.replaceFirst(find, ""), find);
    return 1 + Count(text.replaceFirst(find, ""), find);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Your code doesn't work when `text = "xyxyx"` and `find = "xyx"`. There are two occurrences of `"xyx"` in `"xyxyx"`, but your function only counts 1 of them.

Answer (score 1):

Correct if else condition .replaceFirst() method returns the updated string.We have to update the string.

```
static int Count(String text, String find) {
        if (text.length() == 0 || text.length() < find.length()) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (text.contains(find)) {
            int index = text.indexOf(find) - 1;
            text=text.replaceFirst(find, "");
            if (index!=-1&&text.charAt(index) != 'a'){
             
                return 1+Count(text,find);
            }
            else
            return Count(text,find);
        }
        return 0;
       
    }
```

Comment: It worked for some cases, but if I try to change the value to "xoxoxo" and checking if the preceding letter is an o, it should give an output of 1, but it gives an output of 3.

Comment: You have to change the precedence dynamically . This is only for 'a',

Comment: Change 'a' to 'o'

Comment: I changed 'a' to 'o', but it gives me a logical error, maybe because of the replaceFirst. Do you think using substring would be better?

Answer (score -1):

Just working the answer out in pseudocode, here's how I'd approach the problem.

Define a helper function as follows:

```
countHelper(string text, string find, bool previousWasNotA) = 
  if (length of text < length of find) {
    0
  } else {
    let prefixEqualsFind = if (previousWasNotA and find is a prefix of text) {
        0
    } else {
        1
    } 
    in 
    prefixEqualsFind + countHelper(text without first character, find, first character of text != 'a')
  }

count(string text, string find) = countHelper(text, find, true)
```

The idea here is that `countHelper(text, find, previousWasNotA)` returns the number of occurences of `find` in `text`, not counting any occurences where `find` is directly preceded by an `a`, and not counting an occurence of `find` at the very beginning of `text` if `previousWasNotA` is false.

In Java, this look like

```java
static int countHelper(String text, String find, bool previousWasNotA) {
   if (text.length() < find.length()) {
       return 0;
    } else {
        const int prefixEqualsEnd = previousWasNotA && text.startsWith(find) ? 1 : 0;
        return prefixEqualsEnd + countHelper(text.substring(1), find, text.charAt(0) != 'a');
    }
}

static int count(String text, String find) {
   return countHelper(text, find, true);
}
```

Note that this doesn't work for the case of `find = ""`. But in that case, it's not clear the problem even has an answer at all, since we can put infinitely many ""s together to make a single "" and hence infinitely many ""s are contained in any string at all.

Also note that this is not an asymptotically optimal algorithm. For that, you'll want to use the [KMP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).